# Create button in html that ads an element (ul) to the html file

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've been trying to create a button, essentially an add button that would add an `<li>` element to a `<ul>` list.  I'm not well versed in any JavaScript, but from what I've gathered you can use`document.createElement()`, but how do you attach that functionality to a button and how do you specify where that function will put the element?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking at the following resources:

1. For click handling, you could [add an event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp).
2. For specifying where the element will go, I would look at [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function additem(){
var node = document.createElement("LI");              
var textnode = document.createTextNode("new li");     
node.appendChild(textnode);                            
document.getElementById("myUl").appendChild(node); 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="myUl"></ul>
<button onclick="additem()">Add</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a example.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way give functionality to button is like this:

```
<button onMouseClick="addSomeElement();">
```

Where `addSomeElement();` is your function with appendChild as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ul id="UL">

</ul>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.setAttribute('ID', 1);
    btn.setAttribute('onclick','myfunction2()')
    document.body.appendChild(btn);

}
function myfunction2(){
var ul = document.getElementById("UL");
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("yourItem"));

ul.appendChild(li);
}
</script>
```

this should do , also read about appendChild and Check out this Example about creating button [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_createelement2) and about appending [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_createelement4)